# ECHONEST api 4 NULL pointer exception

Tags: java, api

Below is my code, I'm not understanding the cause of the "ECHONEST api 4 NULL pointer exception":

```
package com.main;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import  java.util.Map;
import com.echonest.api.v4.EchoNestAPI;
import com.echonest.api.v4.EchoNestException;
import com.echonest.api.v4.Track;
import com.echonest.api.v4.TrackAnalysis;


public class SongAnalysis {
    private static final String API_KEY = "14CPBOK0IFN0HRC0R";

    public String getTempo(String fileName){
        return null;
    }

    public static void main (String [] args)throws EchoNestException, IOException{

        EchoNestAPI echoNest = new EchoNestAPI(API_KEY);
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\wooh\\workspace\\SongAnalysis\\songs\\b.mp3");
        Track track = echoNest.uploadTrack(file,false );
        track.waitForAnalysis(30000);
        TrackAnalysis a = track.getAnalysis();
        System.out.println("Tempo" + a.getTempo());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The likely occurrences of your NPE are:

- `echoNest` is null.
- `track` is null.
- `a` is null.

You would want to pinpoint the *specific* location that your `NullPointerException` occurs, then ensure that when you instantiate the object, the object you need is being returned.

Comment: the error is in line where I write (as pointed in the console)
Track track = echoNest.uploadTrack(file,false ); but I'm unable to know the cause , I checked whether the "file" is null or not and obviously it is not null